# MongoRepository Mongo Template Distinct Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I have my API setup as a MongoRepository, but now I have to find to use the distinct values for a field in my object. After lots of research, I have discovered you must use the MongoTemplate format. To prevent myself from refactoring my entire API, I'm trying to implement MongoTemplate on top of my MongoRepository.

This MongoDB command returns the correct value

```
db.collection.distinct("Field.fieldEmbeddedInField")
```

I have put together an Implication class on top of my MongoRepository, but can't get the controller to return the list of distinct values in the localhost.

So we have MongoReposository.java and MongoRepositoryImpl.java

Is this the correct way to implement this special MongoTemplate query. Any suggestions on a query I could use besides distinct that will allow me to have the same results.